# Как добавить новые записи в таблицу SQL Server со столбцом AUTO INCREMENT / IDENTITY?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, csv

Есть CSV файл с полностью совпадающими столбцами с уже существующей таблицей БД SQL Server, кроме одного - в SQL Server есть столбец rid - счетчик, уникальный номер записи в таблице, который является автоматическим.

Необходимо записать строки CSV файла в конец БД SQL Server.

*Детали:*

1. Добавление нужно осуществить с помощью Python.
2. В Python я открыла CSV_file и таблицу БД SQL Server, как DataFrame.
3. `rid` не совпадает с простым счетчиком строк, который показывает в Jupyter

   ```
       rid
   0   451
   1   452
   2   453
   3   454
   4   455
   ...
   211 662
   212 663
   213 664
   214 665
   215 666
   ```
4. Для связки с БД я использую библиотеку `pyodbc`.

Скрипт связки с таблицей:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=название_сервера;'
                      'Database=название_БД;'
                      'username=юзер;'
                      'password=пароль;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM [dbo].[название_таблицы]',conn)
```

Также я попробовала библиотеку sqlAlchemy, но код с ней хочет создать новую таблицу, а не вставить новые записи в уже существующую.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://имя_юзера:пароль@мой_дсн')
датафрейм.to_sql("[dbo].[название_таблицы]", engine, index=False, if_exists="append")
```

Comment: Для каких целей используется pandas ? Что бы добавить записи в таблицу достаточно в цикле пробежаться по записям CSV и выполнить sql-запрос insert https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_insert.asp (rid при этом в insert вообще не участвует, БД его сформирует сама)

Comment: Спасибо. Я попробую сделать, как вы советуете. До этого pandas использовался для преобразования данных в csv и для просмотра записей (для проверки успешного подключения к python). Вы не знаете, как сделать цикл?

Comment: Можете привести в вопросе скрипт для создания таблицы `CREATE TABLE ...` - это поможет понять как именно у вас прстроен столбец с AUTO INCREMENT и является ли он частью PK (Primary Key). Кроме этого уточните пожалуйста метку вашей БД - в вопросе неоднозначность - в одном месте вы указываете `БД mssql`, а потом приводите ссылку на докуметацию о MySQL.

Comment: Сейчас уточню. Ссылку мне выше посоветовал другой комментатор, но она не подходит. Я не создаю таблицу в ms sql, она уже есть с записями. Вниз других записей нужно добавить новые записи с csv файла.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В теории должен работать такой вариант, если в DataFrame'е отсутствует столбец `rid`. Т.е. столбец с `AUTO INCREMENT` на стороне SQL-Server должен отсутствовать в Pandas DataFrame.

```
import mssql
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

# pymssql
engine = create_engine('mssql+pymssql://user:password@hostname:port/dbname')

# pyodbc
# engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://user:password@mydsn')


df.to_sql("mytable", engine, index=False, if_exists="append")
```

PS у меня нет доступа к SQL Server, поэтому я не могу проверить данный код

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112036/discussion-on-answer-by-maxu-------sql-server--).

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pyodbc
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=dagger;DATABASE=test;UID=user;PWD=password")

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
df.to_sql("mytable", engine, index=False, if_exists="append")
```

Данный ответ был получен с помощью связки ответа на данный вопрос и ответа [на этот вопрос.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1168375/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BA-sql-server-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D1%83%D1%8F-sql-alchemy?noredirect=1#comment2028869_1168375)