# Как подключиться к SQL Server используя SQL Alchemy?

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

Необходимо соединиться с SQL Server, чтобы в уже существующую там таблицу закачать строки CSV файла. Подключение осуществляется через pyodbc + SQLAlchemy.

Скрипт связки с таблицей:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={SQL Server};'
                      'Server=название_сервера;'
                      'Database=название_БД;'
                      'username=юзер;'
                      'password=пароль;')

cursor = conn.cursor()

sql_query = pd.read_sql_query('SELECT * FROM [dbo].[название_таблицы]',conn)
```

`select` работает - соединение установлено.

Далее, скрипт добавления строк в таблицу:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://имя_юзера:пароль@мой_дсн')
датафрейм.to_sql("[dbo].[название_таблицы]", engine, index=False, if_exists="append")
```

Но данный скрипт, вместо добавления строк в уже существующую таблицу хочет создавать новую таблицу и выходит данная ошибка:

```
 (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Разрешение CREATE TABLE запрещено в базе данных "master". (262) (SQLExecDirectW)')
[SQL: 
CREATE TABLE
```

---

P.S.

1. я по-разному пыталась написать таблицу: "[dbo].[название_таблицы]",
   "[название_таблицы]", "название_таблицы"- все равно не работает.
2. я знаю про библиотеку pymssql, но она discontinued и ее необходимо
   подключать через виртуальное пространство, я думаю, что могут
   возникнуть проблемы в связи с этим в дальнейшем.

Comment: если под виртуальным пространством вы подразумеваете Conda/Python VirtualEnv, то это наиболее правильный подход, который может обезопасить вас от множества проблем. [См. подробности здесь...](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1002447/211923)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Пример из документации SQL Alchemy](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/mssql.html#module-sqlalchemy.dialects.mssql.pyodbc):

```
import urllib
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=dagger;DATABASE=test;UID=user;PWD=password")

engine = create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
```

PS в зависимости от версии ODBC и версии SQL Server возможно придется подбирать версию драйвера вместо `{SQL Server Native Client 11.0}`.

[Таблица из документации по Microsoft SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-the-sql-server-native-client-header-and-library-files?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=sql-server-ver15)