# pyodbc connect to mssql

Tags: python, sql-server, pandas

Не идет подключение к mssql:
**yodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][DBNETLIB]SQL Server does not exist or access denied.**

```
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

cnxn = pyodbc.connect("Driver={SQL Server};"
                        "Server=127.0.0.1;"
                        "Port=1433;"
                        "Database=db;"
                        "uid=sa;pwd=123456")

df = pd.read_sql_query('select * from table', cnxn)
df.head()
```

Comment: Попробуйте [так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1168383/211923)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем решилось тем, что IDE не выводит df.head(), как например jupyter.
Достаточно было обернуть в print.